# How to put plot statement inside if statement

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot the equity curve on the price, to compare the strategy to simple buy and hold.  To make the graph useful, the equity curve could either start on the initial equity, or in line with the first price on the graph or no equity curve at all depending on manual input.

Using the code below, I get this:

- line xx: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.
- line xx: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.

```
equitycurvetype = input(defval="No", title='Equity Curve Type', options=["No","Yes","Yes same start"])
if equitycurvetype == "Yes" 
    plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)  
if equitycurvetype == "Yes same start" 
    plot(strategy.equity * close[bar_index]/strategy.initial_capital, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
plot(Trailingsl, title = "SuperTrend", color = linecolor ,  linewidth = 2, transp = showSuperTrend ? 0 : 100)
```

Workaround:

```
transp = showSuperTrend ? 0 : 100
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a better solution then hiding.

The drawback of hiding is that tradingview still shows the datapoint as indicator value.

My solution is to do all calculations as normal, but just before the plot add:

```
if CONDITION
   yourvar := na
plot(yourvar)
```

Comment: love the yourvar := na solution. Among other things I use it to conditionally plot otherwise unnecessary plots while debugging/testing

Answer (score 2):

Can't plot from `if` blocks. Also, while using `close[bar_index]` is syntactically correct, it will throw runtime error because of far away referencing in the past, so this code saves first bar's close in `firstClose` variable:

```
//@version=4
strategy("")
equitycurvetype = input(defval="No", title='Equity Curve Type', options=["No","Yes","Yes same start"])
// Save close of 1st bar in dataset using "var" to initialize only once.
var firstClose = close
float equity = na
if equitycurvetype == "Yes"
    equity := strategy.equity
else
    if equitycurvetype == "Yes same start"
        equity := strategy.equity * firstClose / strategy.initial_capital

plot(equity, title="Equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks.  Switching to long only with equitycurvetype is great for comparing different equity strategies vs hold only.